# Emailing form data from a php script

Tags: php, html, forms

I am working on my new website, I am using a template but editing the contents with notepad++. I am currently editing the contact me page in which i am struggling to find a solution to sending the form data to a PHP script which will then send it as an email to me. I have created a PHP script that i think is ok to do the job but it is not working. After I submit some information into the text boxes then click submit it just redirects me to the PHP file in which looks to contain nothing. I have uploaded both the contact page and PHP file to my web server in which the same thing happens only now I will receive an email with none of the information I have entered only the "Hi my name is " stated within the PHP file. I am wondering if anybody knows what the issue is, I have spent majority of the day trying to work this out without luck. I will post both my HTML and PHP code below.

(p.s. I am aware that my "Reason for contact" part of the form will not send as I am still trying to work that one out.

Thanks in advance.

HTML

```
<form name="cForm" id="cForm" action="http://www.richardmotion.com/form-to-email.php" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-field">
            <input name="cName" type="text" id="cName" class="full-width" placeholder="Your Name" value="">
        </div>
        <div class="form-field">
            <input name="cEmail" type="text" id="cEmail" class="full-width" placeholder="Your Email" value="">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="sampleRecipientInput">Reason For Contacting</label>
            <div class="ss-custom-select">
                <select class="full-width" id="sampleRecipientInput">
                    <option value="Option 3">General Enquiry</option>
                    <option value="Option 1">Question About A Guide</option>
                    <option value="Option 2">Question About A Review</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="message form-field">
            <textarea name="cMessage" id="cMessage" class="full-width" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="submit button-primary full-width-on-mobile">Submit</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

PHP

```
<?php
    $cName = $_POST['name'];
    $cEmail = $_POST['email'];
    $cWebsite = $_POST['website'];
    $cMessage = $_POST['message'];
?>

<?php
    $email_from = 'richard.0.motion@gmail.com';
    $email_subject = "Website Enquiry";
    $email_body = "Hi my name is $name,\n
                   \n
                   $message"
?>

<?php
  $to = "richard.0.motion@gmail.com";
  $headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
  $headers .= "Reply-To: $cEmail \r\n";
  mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue with input name filed

```
$cName = $_POST['cName'];
$cEmail = $_POST['cEmail'];
$cMessage = $_POST['cMessage'];
```

And select tag has no name atrribute

Comment: Great it did fix my problem thanks i have it working now, the only issue is it is still redirecting me to a my PHP file. Do you know why it is doing this and how to fix it?

Comment: You need to add header('Location:html_file_name.php'); in your php file at end of the file

Answer (score 0):

1. Your server needs to have a handler for mail() configured, otherwise it will not send. See this for details: [Installing/Configuring Mail](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mail.setup.php).
   You can also use [SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com/) or Google Apps or various other services for sending emails.
2. Your select needs a name for it to send the variable
   ..select **name="reason"** class="full-width" id="sampleRecipientInput">

Comment: Great it did fix my problem thanks i have it working now, the only issue is it is still redirecting me to a my PHP file. Do you know why it is doing this and how to fix it?